# *Compact* Context-Free Grammar for English

Tags: computational-linguistics, resource-request, grammar-formalism, context-free-grammars

I have seen that similar questions have been asked here, but the common answer is to look at Generalized Phrase Structure Grammar. Then, on the internet I just find slides from computational linguistics courses which only include a really small set of rules. Do you know any article-sized (or at least non-book-sized) proposal of a CFG for the English language, i.e. something in-between the GPSG grammar and the minimal grammars reported in textbooks/slides?

Thanks a lot!